# Partial derivatives with component $e^{-y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have to solve the equation $$f(x,y) = x^2e^{-y}$$ calculating the second partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$.

I had no problem for variable $y$, I did it and it is correct.

For the variable $x$ I have a lot of problem.It's not the first time that I had difficulties deriving an equation like this. I tried :

$$ fx(x,y)=2xe^{-y}$$  $$fxx(x,y)=2e^{-y}$$

also for $$fxy(x,y)$$ I had difficulties

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The solutions of second derivatives for x are not correct following my book

Comment: Your solutions are correct.

Comment: Well the first and second partial derivatives look fine. 
Are you sure you have to work out the partial derivatives and not just the derivative?

Comment: yes on second partial..solution must be $$ x(-e^-y)(xy'(x)-2)$$, but I belive in you if my solution is correct

Comment: @Paolo You don't have to believe anyone, just use the internet: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%5E2*Exp%5B-y%5D%2C%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BD%5Bx%5E2*Exp%5B-y%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cy%5D), for example. **Edit:** What exactly did the problem as for? Judging by the book's solution, it's something different from what you're asking here. Can you copy the problem *word for word* in your native tongue?

Answer (score 1):

Your book seems to assume that $y$ is a function of $x$, and not independent on $x$.

In this case when you derive you'll also have the terms with $y'(x)$.

But if you set $y'(x) =0$ (treating $y$ as a constant wrt to $x$) then you'll recover your result.

Comment: understood, thank you very much, now I will try